# EMGU CV Face Recognition from Image

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I've been working with OpenCV before for C++ work and It was working great. Now, I'm developing a C# project and using EMGU CV for gender recognition. I've got problem with predict function. Every time I ran it, program crashed on Predict function, when I erased predict line, it is running. Here's my code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     FaceRecognizer face = new FisherFaceRecognizer(0, 3500);
     face.Load("colorFisherFaceModel.yml");                
     Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("C:\\Users\\sguthesis\\Pictures\\me.jpg");
     cascade = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\sguthesis\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\EmguCV FFR with Image\\EmguCV FFR with Image\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
     FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictedLabel = face.Predict(img1);
}
```

Also, I want to get an output, 1 or 2. 1 for male and 2 for female. I have trained many data that saved on colorFisherFaceModel.yml. It was run well on OpenCV. But I don't know how to use it in EMGU CV.

Comment: "program crashed" is not a good explanation. What errors are you getting in which line?

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question hehe. I've got problem with predict function. When I ran it, it is closed with no error detail. just closing with code 0

Comment: Okay but it's really not clear from our point of view. We have no detail about what's going on in that Predict method. In a situation like this, I usually put a breakpoint and try to see what's happening step by step. So I can't help other than suggesting to get some more debugging knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also working on EmguCV, so I guess I can point few things here,
So first thing is you load "yml" file, Is this file you saved after recognizer is trained or you obtained from somewhere. Because my understanding is first you have to train your Recognizer, what is the structure of the yml file. Why do you load the cascade, where are you going to use it? (normally this is used to detect the face)

If you're saying that program crashed most probably because there are no items in the trained set. (in this case i guess it would be yml file) or as what I've read you need minimum of two faces in training set in order to use Fisher recognizer.

Comment: hii, thanks for your reply. I'll use cascade later for image streaming from webcam. For training set, I used 256x256 images with more than 500 pic. I have tried any picture from internet or camera for detection, but crashed. I have suspected that input image must be the same size of training set, is it true ?

Comment: Well the way I worked with OpenCV/EMguCV is my test image will go through same image processing I've done for training images, ex: when training, training image will be grayed resized and cropped to extract Face rectangle - so when testing also first the test image will go through same flow, until it extracts the image rectangle and resized. So the answer is yes in my case both training image face part and testing image face part is same size

Comment: Yes i can confirm that test image must be same size as training set image, see the error below.

"Additional information: OpenCV: Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 6400 elements, but got 409600."

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the `FaceRecognizer` wants to be trained before the `Predict` method can be called.

You can even load an existing xml Training file by the `face.Load(yourTrainingFile.xml)` method or by `face.Train(yourImages.ToArray, imageIds.ToArray())` method.

Place your `FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictedLabel = face.Predict(img1);` code part within a `trycatch` block the the debugger wont close and you will catch the error message.

PS : if the number of pictures have been changed since the last `Training.xml` file has been created, then it's recommended to call the `face.Train` method instead of `face.Load` method!